# How to put a class method in a variable (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an instance of mysql connection named db.
db has a method named query to execute sql statement

example

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM user',[], callback)
```

To avoid repeating db.query I would like to do something like

```
const sqlCmd=db.query
sqlCmd('SELECT * FROM user',[], callback)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the call to the db object:

```
const sqlCmd=db.query.bind(db)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `new Function()` syntax, it's rarely used though:

```js
const queryDB = new Function(`db.query('SELECT * FROM user',[], callback)`)
//then you can call it as:
queryDB()
```

you can also pass pass arguments as `new Function(['argA', 'argB'], "function body")`

Remember, `[[Environment]]` is set to reference not the current Lexical Environment, but the global one.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do here is called abstraction. Meaning you are adding a layer over the db class. So the simplest solution would be to create a module,
add a method called query.

```
// let db = 'your sql db instance' 

 module.export.sqlCmd = db.query;
```

import this like

```
let sqlCmd = require('path to the above code')
```